Theorem 2.12 in Lieberman's Second Order Parabolic Differential Equations
In Theorem 2.12 of Liberman's textbook the following result is established. Consider a space-time domain $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ ($\Omega$ is not necessarily of cylinder shape in this chapter of Lieberman's book). Let
$$ Lu= a^{ij}D_{ij}u+b^iD_iu+cu-u_t $$
be a second order parabolic operator in the domain $\Omega$, with the coefficients satisfying
\begin{align*}
&a^{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\geq \lambda |\xi|^2\quad\forall \xi\in \mathbb{R}^n\\
&\sum_i a^{ii}\leq \Lambda\\
& |b|\leq \Lambda_1\\
& |c|\leq \Lambda_2, c\leq k
\end{align*}
in $\Omega$. Let $X_0=(x_0,t_0)\in \mathcal{P}\Omega$ ($\mathcal{P}\Omega$ is the parabolic boundary of $\Omega$ defined in this chapter) and suppose there is a parabolic frustum $PF(R,Y)$ with the form:
$$
PF=\{X=(x,t):|x-y|^2+(s-t)< R^2, t<s\}
$$
for some $Y=(y,s)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $R>0$ such that $\overline{PF}\cap\overline{\Omega}=\{X_0\}$. If $u\in C^{2,1}(\Omega)\cap C^0(\bar{\Omega})$ is a solution of $Lu=f$ in $\Omega$ and $u=\varphi$ on $\mathcal{P}\Omega$ for some $\varphi\in C^{2,1}(\bar{\Omega})$ and $f\in C^0(\bar{\Omega})$, then there is a constant $K$ determined only by $\lambda, \Lambda, \Lambda_1, \Lambda_2, n,$ and $R$ such that
$$
|u(X)-u(X_0)|\leq K{\rm exp}((k+1)t_0)(F+\Phi)|X-X_0|
$$
for any $X=(x,t)\in \Omega$ with $t=t_0$, where $F=\sup |f|$ and $\Phi=\sup|D^2\varphi|+|D\varphi|+|\varphi_t|+|\varphi|$.
The proof in Lieberman's book relies on constructing an auxiliary function $v$ with $Lv\leq -1$ in $\Omega$ and $v\geq 0$ in $\Omega$ to employ maximum principle. The auxiliary function is defined as follows: define $r(x,t)$ by $r^2=|x-y|^2+(t_0-t)$ and define $v$ by
$$
v(x,t)=e^{-\alpha R^2}-e^{-\alpha r^2}+4(t_0-t)/R^2,
$$
where $\alpha$ is a positive constant to be chosen. Since $\overline{PF}\cap\overline{\Omega}=\{X_0\}$, it seems that $r(x,t)\geq R$ for any $X\in \Omega$ with $t\leq t_0$. Set $\Omega^*=\Omega\cap\{t_0-R^2<t<t_0\}$, Lieberman claims that from the same calculation as in the proof of Lemma 2.8, one see that $Lv\leq -1$ in $\Omega^*$. However, I really did not figure out how this is proved. Writting down the formula of $Lv$:
\begin{align*}
Lv = &-e^{-\alpha r^2}[4\alpha^2a^{ij}(x_i-y_i)(x_j-y_j)-\alpha(2a^{ii}+2b\cdot (x-y)+1)+c(1-e^{-\alpha(R^2-r^2)})]\\
& +4c(t_0-t)/R^2+4/R^2
\end{align*}
It seems that it is impossible to adjust $\alpha$ so that $Lv\leq -1$ and I do not even know how to prove $Lv<0$. One problem is that we cannot say that for all $X\in \Omega$, $|x-y|\geq R$ since $\Omega$ can be a general non-cylindral domain, therefore it is possible that $|x-y|=0$ though $r(x,t)\geq R$, then the crucial term to achieve negative definite:
$$
4\alpha^2a^{ij}(x_i-y_i)(x_j-y_j)\geq 4\alpha\lambda|x-y|^2
$$
vanishes at such point $X\in \Omega$. Could anyone give me some help in this question? Thanks a lot!
